# Where's the Database in Grover's Algorithm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, computational-physics

I am a little confused by parts of [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Informat.html?id=65FqEKQOfP8C&redir_esc=y) on Grover's algorithm:

Grover's algorithm searches a number of quantum states for a "marked element" $|x_0 \rangle $. The algorithm uses the following unitary operators, acting on an initial state $|0 \rangle ^{\otimes n}$:

$$(-H^{\otimes n}U_0H^{\otimes n}U_f)^TH^{\otimes n}|0 \rangle ^{\otimes n}$$

where it can be shown, that $U_f=I_{|x_0 \rangle}$ corresponds to an inversion about the vector $|x_0 \rangle$ and $H^{\otimes n}U_0H^{\otimes n}= I_{|+ \rangle}$.

> Geometrically, the algorithms can thus be understood as a series of
>   inversions/reflections about vectors in the plane spanned by the
>   vectors $|+ \rangle$ that result from the first operation of the
>   quantum circuit $$H^{\otimes n}|0 \rangle ^{\otimes n}= |+ \rangle
>  ^{\otimes n}$$
>
> [image]
>
> Geometrical representation of a Grover iteration. The algorithm starts
>   in state $|\xi \rangle$, which coincides with state $H^{\otimes n}|0
> \rangle^{\otimes n}=|+ \rangle$. The state is rotated by the unitary
>   operations $U_f=-R_{|x_0 \rangle}=I_{|x_0 \rangle}$ and $H^{\otimes
> n}U_0H^{\otimes n}= -R_{|+ \rangle} = I_{|+ \rangle}$. Every iteration
>   moves the state closer to the solution $|x_0 \rangle$ by an angle of
>    $2 \gamma$.

**But where in the algorithm does the "database" come in that we actually want to search? After all, the computer is initially prepared in $|0\rangle ^{\otimes n}$.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Grover algorithm in real life](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358108/)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate but the answers might be helpful for your understanding.... Concerning the question: The database is the quantum system itself, the one that you initially prepare in the starting state. You are looking for a certain eigenstate and the corresponding eigenvalue, i.e. your system will be in that state after you completed Grover's algorithm. Thus, your quantum system is your "database".

Comment: @lmr I'd certainly say my answer from there answers this question.  Do you think I should re-post it?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree that your answer is highly valuable for the understanding of Grover's algorithm in general. But I would rephrase it for this question so that it becomes obvious where the actual "database" is found.

Comment: @lmr There is no database, that's the point.

Comment: Related: 1. [How is the Grover-Algorithm applied to a database?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5696) 2. [Grover's algorithm: where is the list?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2110) 3. [Does the oracle in Grover's algorithm need to contain information about the entirety of the database?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1419)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a common misunderstanding about Grover's algorithm.  It is not about querying a magically encoded database.  Rather, you have an efficiently computable function $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$ and you want to find some $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)=1$.  Since you know how to realize $f(x)$ (i.e., you have a circuit), you can run $f$ on a quantum computer and use Grover to find such an $x_0$. This function can be seen as returning entries of a "database", which is encoded in a specific function, though I don't particularly like this picture.

The relevance is in the fact that a large number of interesting problems (namely, the class NP) are such that solutions might be hard to find, but they are easy to verify.  Thus, Grover gives a square-root speed-up on any brute-force method to solve such a problem (i.e., any method which does not make use of any special structural property of $f$).

---

(*Note*: This is a slightly edited version of my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/358166/4888, as it was argued in the comments that the corresponding question is not a duplicate.)